# redirect to upi app qr scanner from flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, upi

Can anyone help me? I want to make a payment from my Flutter app using a UPI app, but currently, it directly opens the amount page of the UPI app. However, I would like the QR code scanner page to open instead.

Open QR code scanner pages on click of any UPI app from my flutter app